# C++: Reserve capacity for a std::vector, which is inside another container

Tags: c++, vector

I have following requirement,

`std::vector< std::vector < std::string > > segments;`

There are unknown number of segments, but each segment is of fixed size say 1000. But, I am not able to figure out how do I declare variable *segments* with my requirements.

I tried 

`std::vector< std::vector < std::string >(1000) > segments; // not working`

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you thought about swapping your outer and inner `vector` and altering your business logic according to that ? **Sometimes**, it's as easy as swapping outer and inner `for` loops.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by swapping inner and outer vector.

Comment: Presently your need is: `unknown number of segments, but each segment is of fixed size say 1000`. Now with making changes in business logic, you may change it to `1000 segments, but each segment is of unknown number of strings`.

Comment: Good thought, doesn't work for me..

Comment: @iammilind: That will make a huge difference in the memory layout of the structure, and that in turn can have a great impact in the rest of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You have to loop through and call `reserve` manually. (And for that matter there are no `vector`s inside `segments` yet.. how could reserve space in a nonexistent vector? :) )

Comment: Now I understand. <code> vector<int> ints(100) </code> means, it allocates 100 ints memory locations, once after the declaration?

Comment: @Ringo: Yes, it will create a vector containing 100 elements, initialized with the default constructor of whatever the type in the vector is. (For primitive types like `int`, that will zero-initialize them)

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector` is a dynamic container and doesn't allow you to specify a fixed-size. As an alternative you could look into [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/array.html) (or the versions in TR1 etc.):

```
typedef boost::array<std::string, 1000> Segment;
typedef std::vector<Segment> SegmentVec;
SegmentVec segments;
```

Comment: @Ringo: I know that some people can't or don't want to use Boost, but what's the problem with intermixing?

Comment: I don't see a problem with intermixing, but I would like to stick with std containers.

Answer (score 1):

Just allocate *a single* vector with 1000*segment count elements, and use segment * 1000 as the offset into it.

Comment: Scaling should be amortized; the only problem is that the copying will require lots of memory. But scaling shouldn't be a problem as long as you append new segments at the end.